# jQuery History plugin fires two ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the plugin jquery history in one of my web applications. The problem is, my when i click on a link, i notice in firebug that two ajax requests are sent. What could be the problem? I have attached my code below.
Thank you for your help.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
        $('a[href=' + window.location.hash + ']').addClass('selected');
    // History plugin
    $.history.init(function(hash) {
        if(hash != '') {
            getPage();
        } else {
            $('a[rel=tk]').click(function () {
                var hash = this.href;
                hash = hash.replace(/^.*#/, '');
                $.history.load(hash);           
                $('a[rel=tk]').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                $(this).next('.loading').show();

                getPage();

                return false;
            });
        }
    });
        function getPage() {
    var page = 'page=' + encodeURIComponent(document.location.hash);
    // Filter pages
    $.ajax({
    url: "loader.php",  
    type: 'GET',        
    data: page,     
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {  
            // Show Loadin icon
        $('.loading').hide();
        // Load content 
        $('#canvas').html(data);
    }       
    });
}
});
```

Thank you for your help!